# Is it ever necessary to refresh receipt if you are using doing server-side receipt validation?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, receipt-validation

I have created an app which has auto-renewable subscriptions.

The following is the logic that I use to know if the user has an active subscription.

- Whenever `paymentQueue(_:updatedTransactions:)` of `SKPaymentQueue` is called, I try to perform receipt validation using following steps
- I check if the local receipt is present. If it is not present I use `SKReceiptRefreshRequest` to refresh the receipt.
- I send the receipt information to `verifyReceipt` endpoint of the App Store server.
- The server returns response which contains information about the subscription expiration date.
- I store the expiration date in the app and present the appropriate UI based on whether the user has an active subscription or not.

---

The App Store review has rejected my app multiple times because the `SKReceiptRefreshRequest` errors out. I am unable to reproduce the error faced by the App Store review board.

While searching the internet to solve the problem, I got to know the following facts about the local receipt-

- The local receipt is always present in the production mode. The local receipt may not present if the app is installed using Testflight or during testing. ([link](https://blog.apphud.com/receipt-validation/))
- The App Store server will return the latest subscription information even it it sent an old local receipt ([link](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/69531))

From the above 2 pieces of information, I deduce that there is no need to ever call `SKReceiptRefreshRequest` in production because the App Store server will provide the latest details even if the local receipt is old and the local receipt is always present in production.

---

In order to get my app through the App Store review, I have decided to remove the `SKReceiptRefreshRequest` as it gives errors in the Testflight builds and is not required in the production.

Can anyone confirm if I am correct to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic has multiple flaws:

1) `paymentQueue(_:updatedTransactions:)` is called in the background and (as far as I know) updates already the local receipt. Also an app downloaded from the App Store always contains the receipt. So there is no need to call `SKReceiptRefreshRequest` in that method.

2) `SKReceiptRefreshRequest` requires the users to input his password to allow the receipt refresh. Since you triggered the method within `paymentQueue(_:updatedTransactions:)`, which was called in the background, I reckon this is the problem why the refresh request failed and Apple rejected your app. Nevertheless this method has its reason for being: in production you need it to allow users to restore purchases after reinstalling the app or on other devices and for debug and TestFlight builds you need it to get the latest receipt.

3) You shouldn't send the receipt from your app to Apple's endpoint

> **Warning**
>
> Do not call the App Store server verifyReceipt endpoint from your app. You can't build a trusted connection between a user’s device and the App Store directly, because you don’t control either end of that connection, which makes it susceptible to a man-in-the-middle attack.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/validating_receipts_with_the_app_store)

**How to proceed?**

I would recommend to do the following things:

1) Do not trigger `SKReceiptRefreshRequest` in `paymentQueue(_:updatedTransactions:)`

2) If not already done provide a "restore purchases" button in your app (which calls `SKReceiptRefreshRequest`)

3) Implement [local](http://%20https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html) or [server-to-server](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/validating_receipts_with_the_app_store) receipt validation

Comment: For server to server receipt validation, how is my server notified about a purchase, so I can call the App Store Server API? Is there some webhook I need to setup somewhere? I can't see this in the docs.

Comment: @GregQuinn [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/subscriptions_and_offers/enabling_app_store_server_notifications) you find the documentation from Apple regarding server notification

Comment: Schroder
That only applies to subscriptions/refunds, I'm looking for how to set it up for regular in-app purchases.

Comment: @GregQuinn sorry. Then I have misunderstood you, sorry. As far as I know, Apple doesn't send server notifications for non-subscription based purchases. I guess you have to sync those with your server yourself.

Answer (score -1):

I have used the following way to generate the receipt and send the generated receipt to server for verification:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/validating_receipts_with_the_app_store

Comment: Link only answers tend to end up in the review queues and usually get deleted.

Comment: In the code snippet on that page, you can see that if the receipt is not present, nothing is done. In my app, if the receipt is not present, I try to refresh receipt. The reviewers from Apple got errors when the receipt was refreshed.